# vim remap <C-r>n not working colemak

Tags: vim, remap, colemak

So, i'm a colemak user, and I'm trying vim for the first time.

As a colemak user, I'm using colemak.vim, so my movement isn't on `k,h,l,j`, but `u,n,i,e`

Right now, I'm trying to remap the `CTRL-w(movement): Change focus to the window in the direction (h,j,k,l) indicated` to colemak use. I'm doing right this:

```
nnoremap <C-r>n <C-w>h|xnoremap <C-r>n <C-w>h| 
nnoremap <C-r>u <C-w>k|xnoremap <C-r>u <C-w>k| 
nnoremap <C-r>e <C-w>j|xnoremap <C-r>e <C-w>j| 
nnoremap <C-r>i <C-w>l|xnoremap <C-r>i <C-w>l|
```

But if I press CTRL-r(n,u,e,i) it does not work. Actually, the CTRL-r(h,k,j,l) it works, that is quite strange.

What am I doing wrong? Could someone help me please?

Thanks

Comment: Why didn't you give  u,n,I,e within < and > ?

Comment: Oh, I'm a Mac OS user

Comment: SibiCoder, didn't worked:

`nnoremap <C-r><n> <C-w>h|xnoremap <C-r><n> <C-w>h| `

Comment: That's already in the plugin right? https://github.com/jooize/vim-colemak/blob/master/plugin/colemak.vim#L90

Comment: Yes, that's already in the plugin, but does not work. It is just this that does not work

Comment: There is a vi stackexchange: https://vi.stackexchange.com/